# How do I create new objects for my arrays in method

Tags: python, arrays, object, scope

I would like to pass in a function so I can different functions for different objects. I need that functionality for this project. This is my code so far. The Obj objects were made for testing the function I'm trying to make.

```
import math 
import random
from obj import Obj

def CreateStandardArray(size,data = 0):

  length = math.ceil(math.sqrt(size))
  a = []
  for i in range(0,length):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(0, length):
      a[i].append(data)

  return a

def NewObjs():
  a = Obj()
  a.setnum(random.randint(0,100))
  a.setbool(random.randint(0,1))
  return a
  
  
  
def CreateObjArray(size,data,dataset):
  length = math.ceil(math.sqrt(size))
  a = [] 
  for i in range(0,length):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(0,length):
      a[i].append(data)
      data = dataset
      

  return a



def PrintArray(arr):
  print('\n')
  for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    print(arr[i])

a = CreateStandardArray(25,'a')
PrintArray(a)

b = CreateObjArray(16,Obj(),NewObjs())
PrintArray(b)
```

The output looks like this right now:

```
[Obj::[N:83 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1]]
[Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1]]
[Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1]]
[Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1], Obj::[N:6 B:1]]
```

That repeat after the second object I shouldn't be happening. Is this a quirk for the language?

Comment: The first element output by `CreateObjArray()` uses the value from `data`, all the rest use the value from `dataset`.  Executing `data = dataset` multiple times has no further effect.  If you want the elements to all be different, you should be calling `Obj()` or `NewObjs()` *inside the loop*.

Comment: Okay, I see I was hoping I would be able to pass an actual function in instead of its values, dang.

Comment: You certainly *can* pass in the function to be used for creating the objects.  You just need to *not call it* outside of `CreateObjArray()` (since you would then be passing a single object), but *do* call it inside that function.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. So don't call it outside of `CreateObjArray`?

Comment: Right.  If *you* call it outside the function, it only gets called once, no matter how many times the result gets used inside the function.  The actual call has to happen inside the loop in order to create multiple distinct objects.